# Alternate ways to handle Robot Class Steps in Selenium Test

Tags: java, selenium

My application supports only IE currently. In one case, it opens a pop up window with some fields which are not inspect-able. I am using Robot class features (tab sequences, mouse clicks, sendkeys) to enter data, do a search and other steps on that.

This scenarios works fine in my local but due to large volume of my scenarios we are running them in bulk on cloud machines where the Robot keys functions are not supporting.

Is there any alternate ways to handle this case to continue my scenarios running on virtual machines.

Have anyone faced such cases & can you share your experience handling it in selenium script

Robot class was the option tried which is working in local, need solution to run them on virtual machines.

Tried Switch to pop up window, frame - those are not working as well, the pop window is not getting identified itself (In the window its displayed as Search -- WebPage Dialog)

Below is a sample code snippet - i am using for a search function in the pop up using Robot Class

```
try {
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 sendTab(34);
 sendRobotKey("enter");
 String name ="ABC";
 copyToClipboard(name);
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 cntrolVRobotKey();
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 sendRobotKey("enter");
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 sendTab(4);
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 sendTab(1);
 sendRobotKey("enter");
} 
catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a complete minimal verifiable example?

Comment: The elements are usually identifiable.  Post the markup.  The exceptions would be something that is embedded into the browser.  Or a media file that has no markup at all...  Robot will be a pain to use in different platforms/resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoIt instead of robot class